# What recreational drugs have especially negative interactions with bipolar disorder?

Tags: reference-request, drugs, bipolar-disorder, mental-illness

I'm trying to find out which recreational drugs have the biggest negative interactions with BD (bipolar disorder types I and II) but haven't been able to find strong research.

I especially interested in the interactions of hallucinogens & psychedelics with bipolar disorder, especially the tryptamine class of psychedelics (*e.g.* LSD, psilocybin, DMT). Interactions of stimulants with BD (*e.g.*, cocaine, adderall) are well-documented and I'm less curious about that.

Can anyone point me to sources and/or share your own knowledge?